# Why is the 'if [ $1="1" ]' branch always selected even if $1 is not 1?

Tags: bash, shell, test

I have a shell script named 'teleport.sh' like this:

```
if [ $1="1" ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Sun
elif [ $1="2" ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Moon
elif [ $1="3" ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Earth
fi
```

When I execute:

```
sh teleport.sh 2 testfile
```

This `testfile` is moved to the `~/lab/Sun` directory, which confuses me a lot as I didn't pass 1 or '1' to that script.

What's wrong here?

Comment: +1 for *lab*, *Sun*, *Moon*, *Earth* and *teleport*. But you should **always** double quote expansions (`$var`, `$(cmd)`, and even `\`cmd\`` [to which `$(cmd)` should be preferred]). There are some edge cases where you don't **have** to quote, but always doing it won't hurt.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, shouldn't double quote means "$var" and "$cmd"? what's the benefit of the round bracket you've mentioned above?

Comment: `$(cmd)` is **command substitution**, (mostly) the same as `\`cmd\``. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using spaces fixes your problem.

```
if [ "$1" = 1 ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Sun
elif [ "$1" = 2 ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Moon
elif [ "$1" = 3 ];
    then
    shift
        mv "$@" ~/lab/Earth
fi
```

Though this is neater:

```
#!/bin/bash

action=$1
shift
files=("$@")
case $action in  
  1) mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/lab/Sun     ;;
  2) mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/lab/Moon    ;;
  3) mv -- "${files[@]}" ~/lab/Earth   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Yes, the spaces are necessary, but I'm wondering why the original `$1="1"` syntax "works" at all (producing a true result). How does the `[`/`test` builtin actually interpret that expression?

Comment: @echristopherson Without spaces, `test` sees only one argument (an "l-value").  Without the other arguments (an "operator" and an "r-value"), there is nothing to test, so `test` just says "ok, well yeah, you gave me something and that must be vacuously true".

Comment: `$1="1"` is `$1` concatenated by `=1`

Comment: when using case, how to set an action to execute when none of the conditions is meet?

Answer (score 11):

First obvious thing is you should provide spaces between the arguments of `[`, `test` or `[[`:

```
if [ "$1" = 1 ];
```

When in Bash, using `[[ ]]` is recommended as it doesn't do things unnecessary for conditional expression like word splitting and pathname expansion. Quoting around double-quotes is also not needed. A more readable operator `==` can also be used.

```
if [[ $1 == 1 ]];
```

Added note: If second operand also contains variables, quoting is necessary as it may be subject to pattern matching if it contains recognizable characters like `*`, `?`, `[]`, etc.. If extended globbing or pattern matching is enabled with `shopt -s extglob`, other forms like `@()`, `!()`, etc. will also be recognized as patterns. See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

With operators like `<` and `>` it may still be necessary as I had once encountered a bug where not quoting the second argument caused different results.

As for the first operand, nothing applies.

Consider this simpler variation as well:

```
case "$1" in
1)
    mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Sun
    ;;
2)
    mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Moon
    ;;
3)
    mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Earth
    ;;
esac
```

Or condensed:

```
case "$1" in
1) mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Sun ;;
2) mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Moon ;;
3) mv -- "${@:2}" ~/lab/Earth ;;
esac
```

`"${@:2}"` is a form of substring expansion or array member expansion where `2` is the offset. This makes expansion start at the second value. With this we may not need to use `shift`.

The added `--` prevents `mv` from recognizing filenames starting with dash (`-`) as invalid options.

Comment: shouldn't you break in each case ?

Comment: @Archemar: no, there's no fall-through (contrary to a lot of other languages).

Comment: @Mat, there's fall-through if you use `;&` instead of `;;` (ksh, bash, zsh only). But then `break` still does not prevent the fall-through, `break` is only to break out of loops.

Comment: That's not arguments to `if` but to the `[` command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah it's a quick-answer mistake.

Comment: Correction: double quotes are **only not needed on the left hand side!** `[[ $foo == $bar ]]` will perform pattern matching, but `[[ $foo == "$bar" ]]` won't.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Of course. Thanks for telling. I had only thought about the current subject. It's now updated.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question of why this is happening, this behavior of `[` aka `test` is [documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments presented to test:
>
> [...]
>
> 1 argument:
>
> Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

You're passing it 1 argument, `2=1`, which is not null, and therefore `test` exits with success.

As other posts (and [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)) point out, if you wanted to compare for equality, you would instead have to pass the 3 arguments `2`, `=` and `1`.

Comment: In a sense this is the only the answer that has answered the question asked (rather than giving one or more recipes that do what the OP wanted to accomplish), and shell can be sufficiently mysterious that know *why* it does the things it does is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to recommend a *portable* yet also neater alternative.  Bash is *not* universal (and if you don't need universal, why are you writing a shell script?)

```
#! /bin/sh
action="$1"
shift
case "$action" in
    1) dest=Sun   ;;
    2) dest=Moon  ;;
    3) dest=Earth ;;
    *) echo "Unrecognized action code '$action' (must be 1, 2, or 3)" >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
mv -- "$@" ~/lab/"$dest"
```

(Note to pedants: yes, I know the quotes around `$action` on the `case "$action" in` line are unnecessary, but I feel it is best to put them there anyway, so that future readers don't have to remember that.)

Comment: "Bash is not universal (and if you don't need universal, why are you writing a shell script?)" — this seems to imply that bash scripting has no use cases.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, that is my considered opinion.  Write portable `/bin/sh` scripts, if you need that; otherwise, write in a  scripting language that is less terrible than shell.  The basic Perl interpreter is in fact *more* likely to be present in legacy proprietary environments and cut-down embedded environments than Bash is.