# Why does -n appear in my bash test [[ condition debug output?

Tags: bash, test

I would like to test if a condition is true or false. Here is a sample bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
var=foo
if [[ $var==bar ]]
then
        echo $var is bar
else
        echo $var is not bar
fi
set +x
```

I expect that the output will be `foo is not bar`, but I get the following output instead:
`foo is bar`

While viewing the debug output, I noticed that the condition was being evaluated with `-n`:

```
+ var=foo
+ [[ -n foo==bar ]]
+ echo foo is bar
foo is bar
+ set +x
```

On the [Bash Conditional Expressions man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) it says

> -n string
>
> True if the length of string is non-zero.

But I'm not interested in whether the string length is non-zero, but rather whether the two strings are equal to each other.

Comment: Related: [Why is the 'if \[ $1=“1” \]' branch always selected even if $1 is not 1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149203/why-is-the-if-1-1-branch-always-selected-even-if-1-is-not-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[[` is behaving as designed, because `$var==bar` is not actually a conditional expression comparing two strings, but a single string (that happens to contain two equal sign characters). Since `[[ ... ]]` only contains a string rather than a conditional expression, its default is to use the `-n` flag to check whether the string is not zero-length, and thus evaluates with an exit code of `0`. This is not what you intended, though, so if you would like to evaluate whether $var is equal to bar, use spaces around the `==` operator to turn it into a conditional expression:

```
[[ $var == bar ]]
```

From the [conditional expressions man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

> string1 == string2
>
> string1 = string2
>
> True if the strings are equal.
> When used with the [[ command, this performs pattern matching as
> described above (see Conditional Constructs).
>
> ‘=’ should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.

Comment: @Kusalananda the problem occurs with `[ ... ]` also; do you think it is important to differentiate in this case? I get the same behavior with `-n` whether I use `[` or `[[`

Comment: `[` is the same as `test` and works the same. `[[` is different. For example, variables do not need to be quoted within `[[ ... ]]`, but they would need to be quoted with `test` or `[ ... ]` (as they are ordinary utilities, while `[[` is a keyword). Also, `-n` will not occur in the `xtrace` output when using `[` or `test` in the way done in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda no need for quotes ? so if `bar` is empty, `[[ -n $bar  ]]` is a valid expression ?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume Yes. Also, `[[ -z $bar ]] && echo ok` would output `ok` for an empty or unset `$bar`.