# IF with OR multiple condition into FOR loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I've a strange problem with conditions in a if construct.
The code below shouldn't print the "performance_schema" and "innodb" strings.

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST -e "SHOW DATABASES" -E | grep -v "*" | gawk '{print $2}' > $DB_NAMES

for DBNAME in `cat $DB_NAMES`; do
  if [[ "$DBNAME"!='performance_schema' ]] || [[ "$DBNAME"!='innodb' ]]; then
    echo "---> $DBNAME selected"
  fi
done

rm -f $DB_NAMES
```

But the output is:

```
---> demodb selected
---> information_schema selected
---> innodb selected
---> mysql selected
---> performance_schema selected
---> tmp selected
```

Comment: You need whitespace around the `!=` operators

Comment: Yes, the `test`/`[`/`[[` commands do different things based on the **number of arguments** it has.

Comment: Related: [Why is the 'if \[ $1=“1” \]' branch always selected even if $1 is not 1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149203/why-is-the-if-1-1-branch-always-selected-even-if-1-is-not-1)

Comment: ... as well, your logic looks flawed; if `"$DBNAME" != 'performance_schema'` is false, then `"$DBNAME" != 'innodb'` is surely true and vice versa. You probably want `&&` rather than `||`

Comment: Yes @steeldriver I've copied here the last try of my code... the first had the whitespaces.
However I tried again for superstition and it doesn't work.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, also for the [ and [[ I tried the different syntax but nothing to do

Comment: @steeldriver
Regarding the "flawed logic" I think you're wrong: the values that `for` loop pass with the variable `$DBNAME` individually can be one of these two (`performance_schema` and `innodb`) or another that I need in the output.

Comment: @XIM, consider when DBNAME == "innodb": the first condition `$DBNAME != 'performance_schema'` is **true**, so the line will be printed. Similarly consider when DBNAME == "performance_schema"

Comment: ... yeah to go full geek it's [de Morgan's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Text_searching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `case` statement will make the logic clear.

```bsh
while IFS= read -r dbname; do
    case "$dbname" in
        'performance_schema' | 'innodb') : ;; # do nothing
        *) echo "---> $dbname selected" ;;
    esac
done < "$db_names"
```

Other notes:

- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder why your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).
- To accurately read the lines of a file, use a `while read` loop: see [bash FAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: The goal has been achieved and I will use your code for my script, but I would have liked to have obtained the same result using the `for` and `if` with the `or`.
Thanks anyway and thanks for the tips on the use of "ALLCAPS": I will follow your advice.

Comment: As steeldriver commented, change `||` to `&&`. Logically you want `(!A) && (!B) ` or `! (A || B)`