# Problem in if statement condition in bash

Tags: shell-script

I have following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
echo "Enter your name: "
read name

if [ ${name}=="sam" ]  
then
        echo "Hi Sam!"
else
        echo "Who the hell are you?"
fi
```

I want it to display "Who the hell are you?" if the entered name is not "sam". But it displays "Hi Sam!" even when I enter random string.

What is the problem here?

Comment: 1. Put double quotes around "$name"; 2. insert spaces around the == operator.

Comment: Closely related: [Why is the 'if \[ $1=“1” \]' branch always selected even if $1 is not 1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149203/why-is-the-if-1-1-branch-always-selected-even-if-1-is-not-1)

Comment: This script is unnecessarily rude to people that are not named sam.

Comment: @jesse_b it's even more rude to people named "sam", since it doesn't respect their name capitalization choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read bash tutorials and manual on using conditional expressions, e.g. `[ ]` and `test`.

In short:

1. There's no need to use `==`, as `=` is enough.
2. You must put spaces before and after `=` because otherwise instead of comparing you're assigning the right part of the expression to the left one.
3. Do quote your variables

The net result:

```bsh
if [ "${name}" = "sam" ]
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that it is incorrect to use `==` with `[`, it will work in some shells but `==` is a bashism and should be used only with `[[` tests.  Additionally there is no need to use `${name}`, `$name` will suffice.

Comment: No, `if [ "${name}"=="sam" ]; then ...` doesn't assign anything to anything. It just succeeds and takes the `then` branch, no matter what value `$name` has.

Comment: Actually it does: `a=="1";echo $a => =1`

Comment: Not in `[ a=="1" ]`